# *.api files: what ecosystem do they belong to?

Tags: python, qt, file-extension, scintilla, qscintilla

These files have something to do with python code analysis. More than that, probably. An example:

https://github.com/fastogt/qscintilla/blob/master/qsci/api/python/Python-3.4.api

These files belong either to Python, or to Qt ecosystem. The question would have been trivial; unfortunately the unhappy abbreviation disables the search completely.

What are these files and what does api mean in this particular context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Scintilla code editing component: https://www.scintilla.org

[*.api files and Notepad++](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Editing_Configuration_Files#Autocompletion.2C_aka_API.2C_files)

The `*.api` files are language agnostic; they indeed feature in Qt apps, like Eric IDE, since Qt library incorporates Scintilla as QScintilla. So it has something to do with Python, too.